# Unable to load maps into an android(samsung) phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-maps

Unable to load maps into an android(samsung) phone. It just displays grid cells without loading the maps. This is my first time developing an android application. Could you please help in what else needs to be done apart from the below steps.

Downloaded the android version(eclipse).
Installed all the required API's for google maps.
Set the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.csc714.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>



<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />    
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: what google maps API version are you using? You should be on `v2` and there is no developer key in your manifest so the tiles will not load like you are seeing

Comment: I have added the API key in "res/main.xml" file. However, i also tried adding it to the manifest file. But still the problem persists.
Also, I previously used 4.1.2google APIs. Now, i have changed it to 2.1Google APIs.

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml, add the following element as a child of the  element, by inserting it just before the closing tag :

```
 <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="your_api_key"/>
```

You are missing

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

Few permissions are repeated remove them

Go through the steps in the link. I doubt you have followed the steps from the below link.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start.

You can also follow the tutorial in the link below

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc

Edit :

You also require

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You can also get rid of

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

For more information read

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **google map v2** then first **create(check) api key**.

You have to add `google-play-services library`.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**References:**
[link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)     [link2](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/a-simple-example-using-google-maps.html)

Please refer link and change **xml,java and manifext.xml**

If you find any trouble then let me know.

Comment: I rechecked all the steps from the site given. Problem still persists.

Comment: I am using samsung sII & below is the o/p 

[2013-05-02 01:11:16 - AndroidWifiSocNet] Android Launch!
[2013-05-02 01:11:16 - AndroidWifiSocNet] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-02 01:11:16 - AndroidWifiSocNet] Performing com.csc714.app.Main activity launch
[2013-05-02 01:11:19 - AndroidWifiSocNet] Uploading AndroidWifiSocNet.apk onto device '47410ec71b25c58'
[2013-05-02 01:11:19 - AndroidWifiSocNet] Installing AndroidWifiSocNet.apk...
[2013-05-02 01:11:22 - AndroidWifiSocNet] Success!
[2013-05-02 01:11:22 - AndroidWifiSocNet] Starting activity com.csc714.app.Main on device 47410ec71b25c58

Comment: The file is too lenghthy. Can i have your email id to send?

Comment: are you asking the version of google api? I used 4.1.2 previously. But one of your collegues above asked me to use the v2. Hence chnaged it.

Comment: I am not able to see the link. Could you give me the link again?